# Sorting objects in specific order after sorting by integer value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I am currently trying to sort an array of objects into a specific order.

I currently sort it by levels - which works fine, but then I need to have it ordered as shown below where "Concatenator" type must can only come after and before a "Clause" type as seen below:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 4
  }
]
```

Below is the code I currently have where it currently sorts just by level and an attempt to sort it how I want:

```
conditionsArr = [{
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Clause",
    "level": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Concatenator",
    "level": 4
  }
]


function sortByLevel(conditionsArr) {
  return conditionsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.level - b.level;
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.type === b.type)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  });
}
```

I have tried doing another sort, and looked at other answers for inspiration but I have not been able to get it into the order I need for the second half of the sorting.

Is there any suggestions on how I can sort it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

- group the objects by `level`,
- collect for each `level` `Clause` and `Concatenator` in different arrays
- rebuild a new array by iterating the grouped objects
- use a variable `i` to get alternating `types`.

```js
var array = [{ type: "Concatenator", level: 3 }, { type: "Clause", level: 4 }, { type: "Clause", level: 1 }, { type: "Concatenator", level: 1 }, { type: "Clause", level: 3 }, { type: "Clause", level: 4 }, { type: "Clause", level: 3 }, { type: "Concatenator", level: 4 }, { type: "Clause", level: 2 }, { type: "Concatenator", level: 2 }, { type: "Concatenator", level: 3 }, { type: "Clause", level: 2 }, { type: "Concatenator", level: 4 }],
    order = { Clause: 0, Concatenator: 1 },
    temp = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.level] = r[o.level] || [[], []];
        r[o.level][order[o.type]].push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    i = 0,
    result = Object
        .keys(temp)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .flatMap(k => {
            var r = [];
            while (temp[k][i].length) {
                r.push(temp[k][i].shift());
                i = 1 - i;
            }
            return r;
        });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```